# Execution time in kohana 3

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

How to get execution time and etc. in simplest way in Kohana 3.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Profiling](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/debugging.profiling)

> Kohana provides a very simple way to
>   display statistics about your
>   application:
>
> 1. Common Kohana method calls
> 2. Requests
> 3. Database queries
> 4. Average execution times for your application

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way possible would be to put `<?php echo View::factory('profiler/stats');?>` in your view. I suggest in your template file, right before `</body>` tag.